# OR with integers

Tags: c#, if-statement, operators

Is there a way to use an if statement to check if an integer is equal to another integer(s)? The code below gives an error saying that the || OR operator can't be used for types int and int. Is there a better way to work around this than making each option a separate IF statement?

```
if (role = 7 || 11)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You won!");
}

if (role = 2 || 3 || 12)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You lost.");
}
```

Comment: Note that `=` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If statements require you to evaluate boolean values. So you need to change the second half of your if statement to evaluate to a boolean value:

```
if (role == 7 || role == 11)
```

Note that I changed `=` to `==` because `=` is an assignment, whereas `==` is a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You must use or with the variable i.e.

```
if(role == 7 || role == 11) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: I know :) That's why I told you about it before someone else downvoted you and then +1'd your corrected answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are using = is an assignment, whereas == is a comparison.
your statements require a comparison, then it should be:

```
if (role == 7 || role == 11)
```

In other case, you can use a list to check that:

```
if (new List<int> { 2, 3, 12 }.Contains(role))
{

}
```

OR you can change to using switch statement:

```
            switch (role)
            {
                case 7:
                case 11:
                    Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 12:
                    Console.WriteLine("You lost.");
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or...

```
if (new[] {2, 3, 12}.Contains(role)) {

}
```

The important thing is that the expression in the parentheses of the `if` evaluates to a boolean.